# How to create an array from a select list's text using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hey guys i bet this is an easy question but cant seem to find any help online, i have a select List box and i would like to get each list text and split them up into an array of how big the list box is without the user selecting the value. Right now my list box makes random values so the list can go up to 100

Example

```
<select id="selectBox">

   <option value="1">Select One</option>    <--- I want just the text to input into array
   <option vaue="2">Select Two</option>

</select>
```

Comment: Could you give an example with some code? I'm not sure what you mean when you say "list text" and "how big the list box is". Split them up by what?

Answer (score 4):

There is already that functionality in the HTML Dom

Here is a referencing link for the HTML Dom SelectElement Options http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/coll_select_options.asp

```
var myoptions = $("#mySelectElementid")[0].options;
```

from here you can do the following

```
myoptions.length;
myoptions[0].value;
myoptions[0].text;
```

Answer (score 4):

Use the DOM to get at them:

```
var options = document.getElementById("selectBox");
var optArray = [];
for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
    optArray.push(options[i].text);
}
// now optArray has all the text elements from the option tags.
```